# How to calculate the time between two alterning events in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, data-visualization

I'm looking for a way to get the total time between two alternating events in MYSQL.

I'm using a MYSQL database to store events when a door opens/closes. I'm looking for a way to visualise the total time a door was open each hour.

I'm using datareportive to visualize my data, currently I'm able to show how many times the door opened each hour by the query below:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as hour,
COUNT(*) as num_rows 
FROM events 
GROUP BY hour;
```

The database looks like:

```
ID  door                    Action  date

13  my unique door name!    Open    2019-09-09T09:01:12
14  my unique door name!    Close   2019-09-09T09:01:23
15  my unique door name!    Open    2019-09-09T09:01:30
16  my unique door name!    Close   2019-09-09T09:01:35
17  my unique door name!    Open    2019-09-09T09:01:37
18  my unique door name!    Close   2019-09-09T09:01:40
19  my unique door name!    Open    2019-09-09T09:01:50
```

I'm looking for a way the query returns the total time the door was open each hour.

There is one big catch: sometimes the events Open/Close don't alternate correctly, for example power outage on the doorsensor could result in two times the same event listed in the database.

[SQLfiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/198342/1/0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query to calculate average time between successive events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946916/query-to-calculate-average-time-between-successive-events)

Comment: Saw it before but I couldn't find a solution based on the comments for MYSQL database. Possible because my SQL knowledge is quite limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to suggest something specific without http://sqlfiddle.com/ example. so I can just give you a strategy.

1. create an INTEGER column with `1`/`0` to represent `Open`/`Close` events.
2. Use `SUM(action_int) OVER` (see example here [Calculate a running total in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql)) to calculate running total of opens and closes which will give you unique identifier for each full combination.
3. Self join this results based on this identifier filtering right side to `Open`, left side to `Close`
4. Sum up the difference between `close_date` and `open_date` from previous step to calculate total time door was open.

This should take care of your orphan `Open` events. You probably will have to fiddle a bit with orphan `Close` events to exclude them from the dataset.

Here is sql for Postgres, I believe with minor adjustments you can make it work for MySql:

```
WITH door_events AS (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    door, 
    action, 
    SUM(action) OVER(PARTITION BY door ORDER BY date) AS cycle_id,
    date
  FROM 
      events 
)
SELECT 
  door, 
  SUM(date_close - date_open) door_open 
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   id as open_id,
   door as door,
   date as date_open,
   cycle_id
  FROM 
    door_events
  WHERE action = 1
) AS o LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    id as close_id,
    door as door_close,
    date as date_close,
    cycle_id
   FROM 
    door_events
   WHERE action = 0
) AS c ON o.cycle_id = c.cycle_id
GROUP BY door
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bafb1/19/0

Comment: Is this what you want? sqlfiddle.com/#!9/198342/1/0 I gonna try but any help is welcome!

Comment: which version of mysql do you have?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64)

Comment: I have updated the answer. I don't think version of MySql in SqlFiddler has analytical functions support, so did it in Postgres flavour.

Comment: Thank you! I might be able to switch to Postgres database if i can't port it into mysql.